# React with PeerJS Automatically Answering a Peer Call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webrtc, peerjs

I am trying to build an app where a user calls a user then the other user automatically accepts the call.

Currently I have it as a button saying "answer" (when the call is received) and then the user clicks this button it will begin the video call, but how do I make it so it automatically answers without the user having to click this button?

```
export default function Board() {
    const [me, setMe] = useState("")
    const [stream, setStream] = useState()
    const [receivingCall, setReceivingCall] = useState(false)
    const [caller, setCaller] = useState("")
    const [callerSignal, setCallerSignal] = useState()
    const [callAccepted, setCallAccepted] = useState(false)
    const [idToCall, setIdToCall] = useState("")
    const [callEnded, setCallEnded] = useState(false)
    const [name, setName] = useState("")
    const [randomId, setRandomId] = useState(null)

    const myVideo = useRef()
    const userVideo = useRef()
    const connectionRef = useRef()

    useEffect(() => {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true }).then((stream) => {
            setStream(stream)
            myVideo.current.srcObject = stream
        })

        socket.on("me", (id) => {
            setMe(id)
            axios.post("http://localhost:5000/ex", {
                displayName: firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName,
                me: id
            })
                .then(resp => console.log("Me =", resp.data))
        })

        socket.on("callUser", (data) => {
            setReceivingCall(true)
            setCaller(data.from)
            setName(data.name)
            setCallerSignal(data.signal)
        })
    }, [])

    const getRandomId = () => {
    }

    const callUser = async (id) => {

        axios.post("http://localhost:5000/ex2", {
            me
        }).then(resp => {
            setRandomId(resp.data)
        })

        const peer = new Peer({
            initiator: true,
            trickle: false,
            stream: stream
        })

        peer.on("signal", (data) => {
            socket.emit("callUser", {
                userToCall: randomId,
                signalData: data,
                from: me,
                name: firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName
            })
        })

        peer.on("stream", (stream) => {
            userVideo.current.srcObject = stream
        })


        socket.on("callAccepted", (signal) => {
            setCallAccepted(true)
            peer.signal(signal)
        })

        connectionRef.current = peer
    }

    const changeCall = () => {

    }

    const answerCall = () => {
        setCallAccepted(true)
        const peer = new Peer({
            initiator: false,
            trickle: false,
            stream: stream
        })
        peer.on("signal", (data) => {
            socket.emit("answerCall", { signal: data, to: caller })
        })
        peer.on("stream", (stream) => {
            userVideo.current.srcObject = stream
        })

        peer.signal(callerSignal)
        connectionRef.current = peer
    }

    const leaveCall = () => {
        setCallEnded(true)
        connectionRef.current.destroy()
    }

    const videoDimensions = {
        objectFit: "cover"
    }

    return (
        <div className="">
            <div className="video-container">
                <div className="video">
                    {stream && <video playsInline muted ref={myVideo} autoPlay style={videoDimensions} />}
                </div>
                <div className="video">
                    {callAccepted && !callEnded ?
                        <video playsInline muted ref={userVideo} autoPlay style={videoDimensions} /> :
                        null}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="myId">
                <input placeholder="name" onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}></input>

                <p>{me}</p>

                <input placeholder="to call" onChange={(e) => setIdToCall(e.target.value)}></input>

                <div className="call-button">
                    {callAccepted && !callEnded ? (
                        <button onClick={leaveCall}>
                            End Call
                        </button>
                    ) : (
                        <button color="primary" aria-label="call" onClick={() => callUser(idToCall)}>
                            call
                        </button>
                    )}
                    {idToCall}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                {receivingCall && !callAccepted ? (
                    <div className="caller">
                        <h1 >{name} is calling...</h1>
                        <button id="answerButton" variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={answerCall}>
                            Answer
                        </button>
                    </div>
                ) : null}
            </div>


        </div>
    )
}
```

I have tried putting the "answerCall" function at the end of the "callUser" body but it gives the following error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'renegotiate')
```

I simply want to call a user, then the other user automatically accepts without them having to manually click the "answer" button.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked out an opensource project called Livekit.io?

It's self-described as "an open source project that provides scalable, multi-user conferencing over WebRTC. It's designed to give you everything you need to build real-time audio and/or video experiences in your applications."

Their docs are here: https://docs.livekit.io/